# MediaPlayer instances stay in heap after releasing

Tags: android

[see update below]

I have a button which plays a short sound after pressing it. The sound player class looks like this:

```
public void play (String filePath) {
    ...
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = assetManager.openFd(filePath)
    play(afd)
}

private void play(AssetFileDescriptor afd) {
        try {
            MediaPlayer mVoicePlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mVoicePlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mVoicePlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            afd.close();
            mVoicePlayer.prepare();
            mVoicePlayer.setLooping(false);
            mVoicePlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
        Log.v (TAG, "media released!");
    }
```

The idea is to play a sound and release the `MediaPlayer` and free its memory when it is no longer being used (the sound has completed playing).

But after playing the sound 5 times and looking at the heap dump in Android Studio Monitor, the TotalCount column of the `MediaPlayer` class is 5. Also after pressing "***Initiate GC***" button in the Monitor and then making the heap dump again, it's still 5. Playing one more time makes the count 6. For comparison, the TotalCount of `AssetFileDescriptor` class is 5 before GC and 0 after GC.

The ReferenceTree for those 5 `MediaPlayer` instances (after GC) look similar to this (addresses differ):

[image]

I also tried a variation of the code where the `setOnCompletionListener()` created a new listener inline instead of referring to `this`, but the result was the same.

Why those instances are left in memory and how to deal with it?

[Update]

I've made a few more tests. First of all, it looks like the GC button in Android Studio Monitor does collect the unused MediaPlayer references, but only on its second run. Even if there are 300 unused instances (sound was played 300 times), the first click on GC button does not delete them, only the second click does. This effect was repeatable.

In a second test, I kept playing the sound so many times that an automatic GC occurred on the phone (without clicking on the GC button). It was visible in Android Studio memory monitor blue graph: after Free Memory reached zero, Free Memory was increased by a few MB and at the same time, Allocated Memory dropped (a sign of automatic GC). But the MediaPlayer instances were not released, although there were already 700+ of them in heap dump.

In a third test, I kept playing the sound for a few hundred more times. At some point I noticed that their number on heap dump decreased (but to few hundreds instead of zero).

**So,**

perhaps that's not a problem with my code and this is as designed, the automatic GC itself decides whether and how much instances to collect and clear. And the GC button in Android Studio for some reason does not collect all it could (at least on its first run).

Answer (score 0):

Please try to doing this same this with taking instance variable of MediaPlayer like below.

```
 MediaPlayer mVoicePlayer;
//--------------------
public void play (String filePath) {

    AssetFileDescriptor afd = assetManager.openFd(filePath)
    play(afd);
}

private void play(AssetFileDescriptor afd) {
    try {
        mVoicePlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mVoicePlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mVoicePlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        afd.close();
        mVoicePlayer.prepare();
        mVoicePlayer.setLooping(false);
        mVoicePlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if (mVoicePlayer!=null){
        mVoicePlayer.release();    
    }

    Log.v (TAG, "media released!");
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the result was the same; see my update.

Comment: Are you sure play() method not called multiple time in any situation?Because if this happens than there is case that more than one object created of your media player.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the diagram in the below link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Before calling release player should be in reset state.

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if (mVoicePlayer!=null){
        mVoicePlayer.reset();
        mVoicePlayer.release();    
    }

    Log.v (TAG, "media released!");
}
```